# Internet explorer unable to login to alfresco

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, alfresco, alfresco-share

I modified apache index.html to redirect to my alfresco share site as below

```
<html><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=sameer_abc/share"></html>
```

But whenever I am trying to login via internet explorer, I am getting **Cookies must be enabled in your browser**. I am able to login with chrome and firefox without any problem

But when I change the index.html with my machine ip address,

```
<html><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=192.168.1.10/share"></html>
```

I am able to login in internet explorer.

I tried to change the internet explorer security options too. How to login using internet explorer and I dont want to see my ip address in the url bar.

I am using internet explorer 11.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Its because I have underscore in my machine name.

https://superuser.com/a/332267/306546